# Создание системы мониторинга на Django

Tags: python, django

Я новичок в мире Django. Необходимо создать небольшой интернет-портал для районных школ.

1. У каждой школы есть свой логин и пароль. Оператор авторизуясь попадает на страницу, где  он должен постоянно держать актуальными данные о школе, такие как номер телефона, ФИО директора и т.д. Т.е., как видите, самое простое.
2. Администратор со своим логином и паролем может просматривать, а также редактировать подобную информацию по любой школе.

Начинаю учить Django, а там все примеры по блогу. Хотелось по больше конкретики. Как правильно мне подойти к изучению Django для решения моей задачи? Мне нужна система по сбору данных.

Comment: @derkode, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Ну, тебе вот эта глава наверняка пригодится http://djbook.ru/ch12s03.html , а как освоишь, создать модель профиля школы, думаю, труда не составит. Ну и формочку для редактирования на  фронте по родной документации сделать не долго. Только не спеши, изучай последовательно.